# HomeKit - Changing Lightbulb Color Without Transition

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I am making an app that uses HomeKit enabled lights for notifications. When I write a new value to the hue characteristic of a lightbulb, the color is transitioned from it's current hue to the hue written. So instead of going from it's currently color (let's say Red) immediately to the written color (let's say Purple) it goes from Red, Pink to Purple as well as all the "in between" colors.

How can I *immediately* change the color of a HomeKit Enabled lightbulb from one color to the next without this transition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the accessory that receives the notification from the HomeKit server that the value of hue changed and it decides how to transition from one to another. The app itself cannot 'immediately' transition the color. It is up to the lightbulb itself.

Answer (score 1):

If there is indeed a hard-coded into the light bulb logic board way of changing the hue, and it's only by cycling through the colors, then there is little to do about it.

I can only think of hacks in such case: for example, you might turn the bulb off, then change the hue, then turn it back on, and see if this results in a better transition (I have no idea if this should work at all, but it is worth a try).